# Removing country name from google autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have this autocomplete restricted to one specific country (I did it with `componentRestrictions: {country: 'br'}`, to Brazil) but I don't want to have the name of the country being displayed to every search query (it's so obvious to the user).

[image]

I tried this js function:

```
$('.pac-item span:nth-child(3)').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('Brazil','');
});
```

This function only works on the browser console and to only one time (I don't know why).

If I make via css:

```
.pac-item span:nth-child(3){
   display: none !important;
}
```

In this case, the problem was that it removes the state with the country, and I want to display the city + state.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:google-apps-script]?

Comment: Thank you, I removed this tag.

Comment: No but I think it's relevant to know what exactly are you using behind the scenes for people that are not familiar with that library, otherwise with just [tag:javascript] or [tag:jquery] you're not gonna get the proper audience, as this is not a js, jquery issue.

Comment: _“This function only works on the browser console and to only one time”_ - well likely because it is not executed at the right time otherwise ... Check the documentation of the automcomplete thing you are using there, what kind of events/callbacks it offers, to get your own code run after it has populated the new results.

Comment: @CBroe you're right. The autocomplete goes with the calling 'google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);' and I don't know how to make it.